# How to randomise marker colours in the legend when plotting in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

This is the code I have enabled

```
from itertools import*
markers = itertools.cycle([ '+', '*', ',', 'o', '.', '1', 'p', ])

blah blah....

blah blah....

plot(ld,lp, linestyle="", label=liquidname,marker = markers.next())
```

However the problem is that the marker points start to repeat themselves as I've got many values in the legend. https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQ5pS.png

Hence how do I randomise the marker colours in the legend to avoid confusion?

Appreciate any help, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As for the colored marker, you can pass the color when you call the `plot()` function.

As for the random color, how big of a number are we talking about? You could just define an **array of colors** and randomly pick one:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from random import randint

markers = [ '+', '*', ',', 'o', '.', '1', 'p']
colors = ['b', 'g', 'r', 'c', 'm', 'y', 'k']

for x in range(20):
    c = randint(0,6)
    plt.plot(x, 1, color=colors[c], marker=markers[x%7])

plt.show()
```

[image: markers]

The advantage here is that you have clearly distinguishable colors.

If you've got more than a couple of dozens of markers maybe picking a random numerical color by random RGB components could work.

See also the [Markers](http://matplotlib.org/api/markers_api.html) reference.

Answer (score 1):

Just do the same for `color` as your do for `marker`, although with a different number of colors so that there is an offset:

```
from itertools import *

markers = itertools.cycle([ '+', '*', ',', 'o', '.', '1', 'p', ])
# Use any combination of colors you like.
# Below is blue, green, red, black, yellow, magenta
colors = itertools.cycle('bgrkym')

blah blah....

plot(ld, lp, linestyle="", label=liquidname, 
     marker=markers.next(), color=colors.next())
```

See the [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html) for more information on particular colors.